# upper bound formula the binomial coefficients with real valued arguments

Tags: binomial-coefficients, improper-integrals, proof-explanation, boundary-value-problem, exponential-sum

I'm trying to prove the following.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N},m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},\alpha\in (n-1,n)$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}:N\ge m+1$.

Prove that

\begin{align} 
&\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\Big{|}\binom{n+m-\alpha}{k}(-1)^k\Big{|}\le\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{\exp{((n+m-\alpha)^2+n+m-\alpha})}{k^{n+m+1-\alpha}}\le\\
&\le\int_N^\infty \frac{\exp{((n+m-\alpha)^2+n+m-\alpha})}{k^{n+m+1-\alpha}}dk=\frac{\exp{((n+m-\alpha)^2+n+m-\alpha})}{N^{n+m-\alpha}(n+m-\alpha)}
\end{align}

The first $\le$ is tricky for me.

I have found out for the second $\le$ so called the **integral test**, but not sure is it the right approach.

Comment: What is your reason for thinking the first inequality is true? What's the source, please?

Comment: I'm working on [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276467805_A_Numerical_Method_to_Solve_Higher-Order_Fractional_Differential_Equations). Page 4

Comment: OK. Non-members of Researchgate can access http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04579

Comment: $\binom{n+m-\alpha}{k}=\frac{(n+m-\alpha)(n+m-\alpha-1)\cdots(n+m-\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$

Using Pochhammer symbol and its properties
$$(n+m-\alpha)_k:=(n+m-\alpha)(n+m-\alpha-1)\cdots(n+m-\alpha-k+1)$$

 
$$(n+m-\alpha)_k=\frac{\Gamma(n+m-\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+m-\alpha-k)}$$

So $\binom{n+m-\alpha}{k}=\frac{\Gamma(n+m-\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+m-\alpha-k)k!}$. Don't know what next.

Also in this articel we know that $\binom{r}{k}(-1)^k=\frac{\Gamma(k-r)}{\Gamma(-r)k!},r>0,k\in\mathbb{N}$, but still don't know what next.

Comment: For those who might get confused by the mass of sumvs, the goal is to prove that ${n \choose k}\leq e^{n(n+1)}/k^{n+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to show the first inequality we need to show that $\binom{n}{k}\leq 2^{n^2+n}/k^{n+1}$. Now observe 
\begin{align*}
\log \Big(\frac{n^n}{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}} \Big)&=n\log n-k\log k -(n-k)\log (n-k) \\
&=(n-k)\log n -(n-k)\log (n-k) +k\log n-k\log k\\
&=-(n-k)\log (\frac{n-k}{n}) -k\log (\frac{k}{n})%=nH(k/n),
\end{align*}
where the second equality follows by adding and subtracting the term $k\log n$ and the last equality follows by definition of the Binary entropy function.
 Finally we make the observation that
$$
  \binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}
\approx \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\pi \sqrt{k(n-k)}} \frac{n^n}{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}} 
  =\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi k(n-k)}}2^{nH(k/n)}.
$$
using Stirling approximation.
Hence it remains to show that $\log\binom{n}{k}\approx nH(k/n)\leq n^2-n\log k$. Indeed this is true since $H(k/n)\leq 1\leq n-\log n\leq n-\log k$, which proves the inequality for $n>3$ and using $H(\alpha)< 1$. ( in fact we obtain a stronger upper bound that desired).